# array changes its size when length property is changed. How does array knows the length is changed?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arr = [];
console.log(arr); //output: []

arr.length = 5;
console.log(arr); //output: [,,,,]

arr.length = 2;
console.log(arr);  //output: [,]
```

How does the `length` property of an array works? How does the array knows that the property is changed?

Comment: Its prototype is a host object, it can do whatever it wishes.

Comment: ok, if it is a prototype then how will I create such a prototype?

Comment: The point of host objects is that they can do stuff your objects can't. ES5 adds a way to have getters and setters but do look up the compability.